# Toggle based on checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table which has tasks with several statuses, user can use filter check-boxes to show and hide rows based on these status filters.

```
 function toggleRows(checkBox, img) {
    var show = $("#" + checkBox).prop("checked");
    var rows = $('tr img[src="../_layouts/15/images/' + img + '.png"]').closest('tr')

    if (show) {
        rows.show();
    }
    else {
        rows.hide();
    }
}
```

Implementation can be,

```
toggleRows("taskFinishedCb", "finished");
```

I would put table's code too but I am not allowed to touch that and only code above needs to be improved.

Comment: jQuery can show/hide an element based on a boolean variable with `.toggle()`. Instead of `if (show) ...` just use `rows.toggle(show);`

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I don't like the first two lines of code, but I'm aware that you're only concerned with this function and I wouldn't know how to improve those two lines without seeing the calling function. However:

**Do the checkbox and rows share a common (and close) parent?**

Example markup:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <img src="../layouts/15/images/finished.png" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" value="some value">
    </td>
</tr>
```

In this case, the `img` and `input` share the same `tr`. Meaning you could have this instead:

```
var $row = $('tr img[src="../_layouts/15/images/' + img + '.png"]').closest('tr');
var show = $('#' + checkBox, $row).prop('checked');
```

Specifically looking at this code: `$('#' + checkBox, $row)`. Here we are looking for an element with the `id` specified within the context of `$row`. The advantage of this is that `jQuery` doesn't traverse the whole DOM looking for that input, it only looks within the `tr`. This won't make much of a difference in this case - but it's important to have this approach with performance in mind on client side. You may have also noticed that I renamed `rows` to `$row`? A lot of people will prefix a variable with a `$` if the variable is a `jQuery` selector, this gives other developers a bit more visibility.

**Ternary operator**

Instead of your if/else here you could use a ternary operator to reduce the lines of code:

```
show ? rows.show() : rows.hide();
```

**Naming variables**

The function variable names are a bit ambiguous in my opinion. To me `checkBox` suggests I'm actually receiving a checkbox not the ID property. The same with `img` applies here. More suitable ones might be:

```
function toggleRows(checkboxId, imgName)
```

Answer (score 1):

Selecting the rows by the URL of the images is a terrible idea. Not only is it slow, it links two things that should be unrelated. Considering these are statuses and considering each table row directly represents a task item, you should be using classes on the table rows instead:

```
<tr class="finished"> ... </tr>

function toggleRows(checkBox, status) {
    var show = $("#" + checkBox).prop("checked");
    var rows = $('tr.' + status);

    rows.toggle(show);
}
```

---

Another thing: I assume there are multiple checkboxes? Then this won't work, because you'll have several checkbox checked at once, you should be filtering by all of those. How/when exactly do you trigger `toggleRows()`?

Answer (score 0):

toggleRows should not take a checkbox id but a ***show*** variable to show/hide the row by doing so you can call this method from any where.

```
function toggleRows(show, img) {
    var rows = $('tr img[src="../_layouts/15/images/' + img + '.png"]').closest('tr')
    if (show) {
       rows.show();
    }
    else {
    rows.hide();
 }
}

function ShowOrHide() {
     var checkbox = $("#" + checkBox);
     var show = checkbox.prop("checked");
     toggleRows(show, "finished");
}
```

Might be a nitpicking on your code but that is what I have found

Comment: What is the variable `checkBox` in the first line of `ShowOrHide()`?

Comment: checkbox variable is the id of the checkbox .